# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (64) must match the size of tensor b (128) at non-singleton dimension 3

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to train the model. In the model vgg16 with first ten (10) layers has been used as a frontend. Now I want to change its network from 10 to 13 layers of vgg16. the following error has occurred.
Runtime Error: The size of tensor a (64) must match the size of tensor b (128) at non-singleton dimension 3

Here is the error stacktrace :

```
G:\Saadain\Anaconda\envs\CSRNet\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:528: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([1, 1, 85, 128])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1, 1, 42, 64])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
  return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 230, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 92, in main
    train(train_list, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch)
  File "train.py", line 145, in train
    loss = criterion(output, target)
  File "G:\Saadain\Anaconda\envs\CSRNet\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Saadain\Anaconda\envs\CSRNet\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 528, in forward
    return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
  File "G:\Saadain\Anaconda\envs\CSRNet\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2928, in mse_loss
    expanded_input, expanded_target = torch.broadcast_tensors(input, target)
  File "G:\Saadain\Anaconda\envs\CSRNet\lib\site-packages\torch\functional.py", line 74, in broadcast_tensors
    return _VF.broadcast_tensors(tensors)  # type: ignore
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (64) must match the size of tensor b (128) at non-singleton dimension 3
```

The model defintion :

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
from torchvision import models
from utils import save_net,load_net
class CSRNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, load_weights=False):
        super(CSRNet, self).__init__()
        self.seen = 0
        self.frontend_feat = [64,64,'M',128,128,'M',256,256,256,'M',512,512,512,'M',512,512,512,]
        self.backend_feat  = [512, 512, 512,256,128,64]
        self.frontend = make_layers(self.frontend_feat)
        self.backend = make_layers(self.backend_feat,in_channels = 512,dilation = True)
        self.output_layer = nn.Conv2d(64, 1, kernel_size=1)
        if not load_weights:
            mod = models.vgg16(pretrained = True)
            self._initialize_weights()
            for i in range(len(self.frontend.state_dict().items())):
                list(self.frontend.state_dict().items())[i][1].data[:] = list(mod.state_dict().items())[i][1].data[:]
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.frontend(x)
        x = self.backend(x)
        x = self.output_layer(x)
        return x
    def _initialize_weights(self):
        for m in self.modules():
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                nn.init.normal_(m.weight, std=0.01)
                if m.bias is not None:
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
            elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
                nn.init.constant_(m.weight, 1)
                nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0) 
def make_layers(cfg, in_channels = 3,batch_norm=False,dilation = False):
    if dilation:
        d_rate = 2
    else:
        d_rate = 1
    layers = []
    for v in cfg:
        if v == 'M':
            layers += [nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)]
        else:
            conv2d = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, v, kernel_size=3, padding=d_rate,dilation = d_rate)
            if batch_norm:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.BatchNorm2d(v), nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            else:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            in_channels = v
    return nn.Sequential(*layers)
```

And the train function :

```
import sys
import os

import warnings

from model import CSRNet

from utils import save_checkpoint

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

import numpy as np
import argparse
import json
import cv2
import dataset
import time

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch CSRNet')

parser.add_argument('train_json', metavar='TRAIN',
                    help='path to train json')
parser.add_argument('test_json', metavar='TEST',
                    help='path to test json')

parser.add_argument('--pre', '-p', metavar='PRETRAINED', default=None,type=str,
                    help='path to the pretrained model')

parser.add_argument('gpu',metavar='GPU', type=str,
                    help='GPU id to use.')

parser.add_argument('task',metavar='TASK', type=str,
                    help='task id to use.')

def main():
    
    global args,best_prec1
    
    best_prec1 = 1e6
    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.original_lr = 1e-7
    args.lr = 1e-7
    args.batch_size    = 1
    args.momentum      = 0.95
    args.decay         = 5*1e-4
    args.start_epoch   = 0
    args.epochs = 400
    args.steps         = [-1,1,100,150]
    args.scales        = [1,1,1,1]
    args.workers = 4
    args.seed = time.time()
    args.print_freq = 30
    with open(args.train_json, 'r') as outfile:        
        train_list = json.load(outfile)
    with open(args.test_json, 'r') as outfile:       
        val_list = json.load(outfile)
    
    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = args.gpu
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(args.seed)
    
    model = CSRNet()
    
    model = model.cuda()
    
    criterion = nn.MSELoss(size_average=False).cuda()
    
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), args.lr,
                                momentum=args.momentum,
                                weight_decay=args.decay)

    if args.pre:
        if os.path.isfile(args.pre):
            print("=> loading checkpoint '{}'".format(args.pre))
            checkpoint = torch.load(args.pre)
            args.start_epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
            best_prec1 = checkpoint['best_prec1']
            model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
            optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])
            print("=> loaded checkpoint '{}' (epoch {})"
                  .format(args.pre, checkpoint['epoch']))
        else:
            print("=> no checkpoint found at '{}'".format(args.pre))
            
    for epoch in range(args.start_epoch, args.epochs):
        
        adjust_learning_rate(optimizer, epoch)
        
        train(train_list, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch)
        prec1 = validate(val_list, model, criterion)
        
        is_best = prec1 < best_prec1
        best_prec1 = min(prec1, best_prec1)
        print(' * best MAE {mae:.3f} '
              .format(mae=best_prec1))
        save_checkpoint({
            'epoch': epoch + 1,
            'arch': args.pre,
            'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'best_prec1': best_prec1,
            'optimizer' : optimizer.state_dict(),
        }, is_best,args.task)

def train(train_list, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch):
    
    losses = AverageMeter()
    batch_time = AverageMeter()
    data_time = AverageMeter()
    
    
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset.listDataset(train_list,
                       shuffle=True,
                       transform=transforms.Compose([
                       transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                     std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
                   ]), 
                       train=True, 
                       seen=model.seen,
                       batch_size=args.batch_size,
                       num_workers=args.workers),
        batch_size=args.batch_size)
    print('epoch %d, processed %d samples, lr %.10f' % (epoch, epoch * len(train_loader.dataset), args.lr))
    
    model.train()
    end = time.time()
    
    for i,(img, target)in enumerate(train_loader):
        data_time.update(time.time() - end)
        
        img = img.cuda()
        img = Variable(img)
        output = model(img)
        
        
        
        
        target = target.type(torch.FloatTensor).unsqueeze(0).cuda()
        target = Variable(target)
        
        
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        
        losses.update(loss.item(), img.size(0))
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()    
        
        batch_time.update(time.time() - end)
        end = time.time()
        
        if i % args.print_freq == 0:
            print('Epoch: [{0}][{1}/{2}]\t'
                  'Time {batch_time.val:.3f} ({batch_time.avg:.3f})\t'
                  'Data {data_time.val:.3f} ({data_time.avg:.3f})\t'
                  'Loss {loss.val:.4f} ({loss.avg:.4f})\t'
                  .format(
                   epoch, i, len(train_loader), batch_time=batch_time,
                   data_time=data_time, loss=losses))
    
def validate(val_list, model, criterion):
    print ('begin test')
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset.listDataset(val_list,
                   shuffle=False,
                   transform=transforms.Compose([
                       transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                     std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
                   ]),  train=False),
    batch_size=args.batch_size)    
    
    model.eval()
    
    mae = 0
    
    for i,(img, target) in enumerate(test_loader):
        img = img.cuda()
        img = Variable(img)
        output = model(img)
        
        mae += abs(output.data.sum()-target.sum().type(torch.FloatTensor).cuda())
        
    mae = mae/len(test_loader)    
    print(' * MAE {mae:.3f} '
              .format(mae=mae))

    return mae    
        
def adjust_learning_rate(optimizer, epoch):
    """Sets the learning rate to the initial LR decayed by 10 every 30 epochs"""
    
    
    args.lr = args.original_lr
    
    for i in range(len(args.steps)):
        
        scale = args.scales[i] if i < len(args.scales) else 1
        
        
        if epoch >= args.steps[i]:
            args.lr = args.lr * scale
            if epoch == args.steps[i]:
                break
        else:
            break
    for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
        param_group['lr'] = args.lr
        
class AverageMeter(object):
    """Computes and stores the average and current value"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.val = 0
        self.avg = 0
        self.sum = 0
        self.count = 0

    def update(self, val, n=1):
        self.val = val
        self.sum += val * n
        self.count += n
        self.avg = self.sum / self.count    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: may i know your input size?

Comment: @PrajotKuvalekar there are total 50 images of different sizes

Comment: u cannot use diff size input here.....resize them to specific size

Comment: @PrajotKuvalekar    Like how

Comment: @Akbar you can add 0-padding to make them all the size of the biggest image, or crop them to make them all the size of your smallest image (with RandomCrop for example)

Comment: @trialNerror if I remove the last three layers of vgg16 it works but when i add the last three layers it happens like this type of error

Comment: Hi Akbar, could you please post the complete stack trace for the error message?

Comment: @BedirYilmaz Yes I have sent it to you as well Sir.

Comment: @BedirYilmaz Actually I want to change the FIRST TEN  network layers into 13 and occurred this type of error.

Comment: Please do not add the error messages as picture and please post your training code as well. This is necessary since the error message is thrown from the train.py file

Comment: @BedirYilmaz now added the train .py file only.

Comment: Please add the previously added model file as well, together with the up-to-date error message (in code markup please, not as image).

Comment: @BedirYilmaz can not add both the files as it says you need to add extra context . but I have described in detail so what should I do please help me. And I have also sent it to you via email

Comment: @BedirYilmaz added both the files

Comment: the error as well please

Comment: @BedirYilmaz added

Comment: when you put a breakpoint to line 145 in training.py, what does `output.shape, target.shape` return in the debug console?

Comment: @BedirYilmaz   python train.py    UCF_CC_50_train.json   UCF_CC_50_val.json 0 0        just use this Command in command prompt. An the error occurred after few seconds

Comment: @BedirYilmaz same error

Comment: @BedirYilmaz                                                                                        
 c:\users\gigabyte pc\desktop\counting\csrnet-pytorch-master\train.py(145)train()
-> loss = criterion(output, target)
(Pdb)

Comment: @BedirYilmaz > c:\users\gigabyte pc\desktop\counting\csrnet-pytorch-master\train.py(146)train()
-> loss = criterion(output, target)
(Pdb) w
  c:\users\gigabyte pc\desktop\counting\csrnet-pytorch-master\train.py(92)main()
-> train(train_list, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch)

Comment: @BedirYilmaz > c:\users\gigabyte pc\desktop\counting\csrnet-pytorch-master\train.py(146)train()
-> loss = criterion(output, target)

Comment: You have to learn how to debug your code. Here are a couple of examples for various IDEs - pycharm: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJtWxm12Eo0 vscode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging